# asp.net mvc 2 wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

i was looking how to implement my wizard in asp.net mvc 2 without using TempData or session like in this example: http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/652_Creating_Wizard_in_ASP_NET_MVC_Part_2.aspx?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12514445/494064

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Html.Serialize](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/03/06/persisting-model-state-in-asp-net-mvc-using-html-serialize.aspx) helper from MVC Futures.

Comment: do you have a code sample for this, i dont want to use session btw

Comment: @user603007, this helper doesn't use session. You use the `Html.Serialize` helper inside a form by passing it a model instance. It serializes it using a hidden field and when the form is submitted it will send the serialized value to the corresponding action. On this action you would use action arguments as normally, the only difference is that you would decorate them with the `[Deserialize]` attribute and you will get those instances back. The only requirement is that those model classes are decorated with the `[Serializable]` attribute. It works the same as ViewState in classic ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You could move from screen to screen using GET method and store collected data in URL as parameters.

Comment: that is not a very secure approach?

Comment: I believe it isn't less secure than one described in the article.