# Cannot create an instance of an interface

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, orchardcms

after install profile 1.1, add at least one field to the User Content Types then go to the Users module and click on Add a new user, click save and you should get this error. any help would be appreciate.

### Server Error in '/OrchardLocal' Application.

Cannot create an instance of an interface. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.

Source Error: 


Line 146: public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) {
Line 147: try {
Line 148: _httpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(result);
Line 149: }
Line 150: finally {


Source File: C:\Users\rspaulino\Desktop\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs Line: 148 

Stack Trace: 


    [MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.]
    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +199
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +572
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +449
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder) +17
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +399
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +93
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +53
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +1367
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +449
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +317
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +117
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
    Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in C:\Users\rspaulino\Desktop\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:148
    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8963149
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +
```

184

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237

Comment: Did you try to contact the author of that module? This looks like a bug report, not a question.

Comment: yes I did but didn't get any type of support.

Comment: That sucks. Well, I guess your only option is to fix their code yourself then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wow, ran into exactly the same error today (but not sure if that was the same module)!

It's a bug in one of the view models. Someone had put an **interface** there **instead of class** one (eg. IUser instead of UserPartRecord). Model binder shouts because it cannot create an instance of an object to bind form parameter(s) to.

*Your only option is to change the type of that parameter (which one - you have to find out) to a concrete type. The quickest way would be to create a simple class implementing that interface and replace the parameter type with it.*

**EDIT:** A similar problem was discussed (and solved) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059433/cannot-create-an-instance-of-an-interface-an-mvc-3-wizard-inside-orchard-cms) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215337/mvc-3-cannot-create-an-instance-of-an-interface).

Comment: It seems that an interface is allowed as the type for the @model directive in views, however this error is raised if an interface is the type of a parameter in controller methods.

Answer (score 4):

I started getting this exception in an MVC ASP.Net 4.6 application. It took me some time, but I finally realized that I had change my MVC Controller API call from

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> DoStuff(IEnumerable<string> ids){ ... }
```

To

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> DoStuff(IReadOnlyList<string> ids){ ... }
```

I was avoiding the multiple enumeration of an IEnumerable that R# warns about. Lesson Learned: Don't use IReadOnlyList in this instance.

Here's the full exception:

```
[MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.]
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean&amp; canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal&amp; ctor, Boolean&amp; bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark) +119
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark) +247
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +197
```

Comment: Got into that myself too. You could use IList or ICollection

Answer (score -1):

I ran into exactly same problem with (MVC 5) + (Ninject3.2). The whole DI preparation is very typical and standard, and just cannot make it working. Finally, I did this:

1. Create a default CTOR to your controler;
2. In CTOR, add a line like this:

   ```
   repository=DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IYourinterface)) as IYourinterface;
   ```

I know it is just a workaround, but I think something has been changed in MVC 5 about controller object instantiation. Will dig it out later.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem being discussed here... where the item is trying to be resolved in the method, not the constructor