# Save to Sesssion and redirect on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

A have a simple website with 4 Views(PersonalInfo, PostOffice, OrderDetails, Commentary). All views are strongly typed to a model named Information. What I need to do is following:

- when i click the Next button in PersonalInfo view, I need to store some data into session
- after that, I must be redirected to next View, OrderDetails

Below is an example of how I tried to solve the problem, but it doesn't work

Controller:

```
public ActionResult PersonalInfo(string button, Models.Information FirstName, Models.Information LastName)
    {
        if (button == "Next")
        {
            HttpContext.Session["FirstName"] = FirstName;
            HttpContext.Session["LastName"] = LastName;

            return RedirectToAction("PostOffice", "Home");
        }
        else if (button == "Back")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("OrderDetails", "Home");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Buttons in view:

```
<div>
<button name="button" value="Next">Next</button>
<button name="button" value="Back">Back</button></div>
```

Model properties:

```
//Firstname validation
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field.")]
    [Display(Name = "First name:")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    //Lastname validation
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last name:")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Comment: **How** doesn't it work?

Comment: Doesn't matter which button I click, no redirect happens. I'm not sure if something is stored in session tho.

Comment: And also all validation fields are marked with red, even if i come to the website for the first time and don't type anything.

Comment: Do you even get to the `PersonalInfo` action with the debugger? Do your buttons have javascript to trigger the action?

Comment: I access PersonalInfo through a menu on Index site. The page is displayed properly. And no, I don't use javascript. Isn't there any way to do it with controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're not even generating a request to get to your `PersonalInfo` action.

Make your buttons submit buttons instead

```
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Prev" />
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Next" />
```

And I'm assuming your form action is `PersonalInfo`

In your controller action use `TempData` instead of `Session` to pass info to the redirected action so the data persists only to the next request.

```
TempData["FirstName"] = FirstName;
TempData["LastName"] = LastName;
```

Finally, [multi-step registration process issues in asp.net mvc (splitted viewmodels, single model)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402628/multi-step-registration-process-issues-in-asp-net-mvc-splitted-viewmodels-sing/6403485#6403485) may help you out since you're doing mutli-step form processing.

Comment: I would use TempData, but my assignment requires the use of Session. I can only use TempData in the last step of form processing, where I display all information in one View. Other than that, a lot of useful information. Thank you.