# ASP.NET MVC Wizard issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wizard, modelbinder

Hi i've used this post to create a wizard in asp.net mvc: 
[multi-step registration process issues in asp.net mvc (splitted viewmodels, single model)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402628/multi-step-registration-process-issues-in-asp-net-mvc-splitted-viewmodels-sing/17297735)

It works only with dataannotations on the concrete classes behind the interface 
        IStepViewModel

Is it possible in the StepViewModelBinder to add some functionality to execute a modelbinder on the concrete steps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Unfornutanetely it is not at generic as the original - but it allows modelbinders for the viewmodels.

I replaced the original StepViewModelBinder with the following:

```
 public class StepViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var stepTypeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("StepType");
        var stepType = Type.GetType((string)stepTypeValue.ConvertTo(typeof(string)), true);
        var step = Activator.CreateInstance(stepType);

        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => step, stepType);
        return step;
    }
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        //bind using default binding, and calls the overriden "CreateModel"
        var model = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        //if the modelstate is not valid return to controller with found error
        if (!bindingContext.ModelState.IsValid)
            return model;

        //if the modelstate is valid, call the modelbinder for the concreteType
        var ll = Binders.GetBinder(model.GetType());
        return ll.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }

}
```

this solution gets the associated modelbinder for the model - the downside is, since the concrete implementation is hidden behind an interface, a modelbinder is **required** to work for the concrete implementation, since a concrete type cannot be instantiated from an interface

THe modelbinder for the concrete class could then look as follows:

```
  protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var step = new Step1();
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => step, step.GetType());
        return step;
    }
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = (Step1)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("", "This is a test");
        return model;
    }
```

the modelbinder is coupled together with the viewmodel as usually, either by

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Step1), new Step1ModelBinder());
```

or by class annotation:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(OpretBrugerStep1ModelBinder))]
```

I've just created a generic default modelbinder for the step-implementations that does not need a specific implementation - just to get them to work with the example:

```
public class DefaultStepModelBinder<T> : DefaultModelBinder where T : IStepViewModel, new()
    {
        protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
        {
            var step = new T();
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => step, step.GetType());
            return step;
        }
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var model = (T)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
            return model;
        }
    }
```

Thus the concrete steps kan use this modelbinder - example for step1:

```
 [ModelBinder(typeof(DefaultStepModelBinder<Step1>))]
[Serializable]
public class Step1 : IStepViewModel
{ ... }
```

Comment: I've just created a generic default modelbinder for the step-implementations that does not need a specific implementation - just to get them to work with the example: